# When using identity input, how do you get ggplot to display % symbol next to value label

Tags: r, ggplot2

The below produces a plot with value labels - from a table containing percentages; NOT raw individual level data. So the stat="identity" argument is used. How would you instruct ggplot to add a % symbol to each value label above the bar in such a case?

```
#Generate data table
Percent<-c(20,80)
row_labels<-c("Male","Female")
df<-data.frame(row_labels,Percent)

#Plot data table
ggplot(df) + aes(row_labels,Percent,fill=row_labels) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +  
labs(x = "",title = " ") + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + coord_flip()+ theme(legend.position="none") + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),  
panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) + geom_text(aes(label=round(Percent,digits=1)), hjust = -0.15, size = 3)
```

Comment: Try with `label = paste(round(Percent, digits=1), "%"))` in `geom_text`.

Comment: Unfortunately it just moves the labels away from the tops of the bars to the axis, not sure why. Perhaps the coord_flip() is confusing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified `aes` of the `geom_text` in the following way:

```
ggplot(df, aes(row_labels,Percent,fill=row_labels) ) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity") +  
 geom_text(aes(y=Percent+5, label = paste(Percent, "%")) ) + 
 labs(x = "",title = " ") +
 theme(
  legend.position="none",
  legend.title = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),  
  panel.background = element_blank(),
  axis.line = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
  axis.title.x=element_blank(),
  axis.text.x=element_blank(),
  axis.ticks.x=element_blank()
 ) + 
 coord_flip()
```

Although the order of layers/adjustments does not matter (you have mentioned `coord_flip`), I have reorganised the code for better fluency.

Comment: Excellent, your answers solves it. Though the original font size control mechanism doesn't work with that for some reason, but easily resolved: geom_text(aes(y=Percent+5, label = paste(Percent, "%")),size=3 )